# Using Windows 10 to manage Hyper-V on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2, windows-10

Is it possible to remotely manage Hyper-V running on Windows Server 2008 R2 with the Hyper-V Manager on Windows 10?  I know that the Hyper-V Manager on Windows Server 2012 R2 is not backwards compatible with 2008 R2 (I don't know if Microsoft decided to add backwards compatibility for Hyper-V in Windows 10).

I have a Windows 10 vm with Hyper-V installed and when I try to connect to the host as a domain admin, I get a message that says:

```
An Error occurred while attempting to connect to server "Virtual1".
Check that the Virtual Machine Management service is running and that you are authorized to connect to the server. 

You do not have the required permission to complete this task. 
Contact the administrator of the authorization policy for the computer 'Virtual1'.
```

This error message doesn't tell me if I'm wasting my time or not and I have not found any websites stating that Windows 10 Hyper-V Manager is not backwards compatible with Windows Server 2008 R2. I've tried running `winrm quickconfig` on the host machine, as recommended on another ServerFault page for Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012 R2, but that doesn't seem to help. I'm able to remotely manage Hyper-V on my Windows 7 machine without any problems.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed the RSAT [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520) feature on your Windows 10 box? I believe this is required to administer Hyper-V remotely in 2012/2012R2. It might also help with your 2008 R2 box. However, like you, I'm not aware of any explicit guidance that this is possible (or not).

Comment: Yes, I have installed RSAT.  I was able to get the Win 10 vm to work with AD, DNS, and DHCP.  Luckily, those haven't changed (or at least I haven't noticed). I don't know if RSAT is required for Hyper-V, because the Hyper-V manager had to be turned on in Programs and Features, but I did that after I installed RSAT.

Comment: Hi Have you checked that the Windows 10 user is in the Hyper V Administrators Group on the Windows Server 2008 R2 Hyper V Host. That should be all that is required - Ed. (Don't forget to mark as answer if it helps)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have submitted a ticket into Microsoft.  After 4 days of their tech support, we closed the ticket.  Final answer, NO Hyper-V Manager on Windows 10 will not communicate to Server 2008 r2.

Comment: Thank you for your sacrifice.  Can't believe it took 4 days...

Answer (score 1):

Supported combinations of Hyper-V and Hyper-V manager are documented here :
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/remotely-manage-hyper-v-hosts

Basically, starting with Windows Server 2012 / Windows 8.1 and up to Windows Server 2016 / Windows 10, Hyper-V manager can manage same and older versions of Hyper-V.
For older versions, only the the matching server and client versions of Windows are compatible.